# STLloader and three.js - How to check if file is binary?

Tags: three.js

Um using three.js (r79) and STLLoader for rendering .stl files.

Following piece of code should be processed only if the file is binary, because if it's ASCII - I get an error.

```
 geometry = new THREE.Geometry().fromBufferGeometry( geometry );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code adds a new property to the generated geometry isASCII and isBinary.

```
var loader = new THREE.STLLoader();
loader.parseBinary = function(data){
    var parsebinary = THREE.STLLoader.prototype.parseBinary.bind(this); 
    var result = parsebinary(data);
    result.isBinary = true;
    return result;
};
loader.parseASCII= function(data){
    var parseASCII= THREE.STLLoader.prototype.parseASCII.bind(this); 
    var result = parseASCII(data);
    result.isASCII = true;
    return result;
};
loader.load(url,function(geometry){
    if (geometry.isASCII){
        ...
    } else if (geometry.isBinary){
        ...
    } 
});
```

The loader already separates binary and ascii files. this just makes use of that feature.

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I was looking for